# Number of hypercubes of a $\varepsilon$-fine grid intersecting the unit sphere

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, spheres

I'm investigating an idea to bound the norm of a random matrix on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$. I'm at a point where I need to bound the number of hypercubes of a $\epsilon$-fine grid intersecting the unit sphere. Unfortunately I've no background in geometry nor can I acquire one in time. Since I'm not even able to give a proper definition of what I mean, I drew an image of the number of cubes in $\mathbb{R}^2$ I want to count:
[image]

It would be great if anyone could give me some references if there are theorems in the literature.

Comment: It would be great if one could tell me why they think this is a bad question instead of just down voting it. I really want to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...every cubie that intersects your sphere (in $n$-space, so I'm talking about $S^{n-1}$) contains a point at distance 1 from the origin...so the CLOSEST point to the origin in that cubie must be at least distance 1-D, where $D$ is the greatest distance between points of the cube...which happens to be $e \sqrt{n}$, where $e$ is the edge-length of your cubie. The same argument goes for how far OUTSIDE the sphere it can be.

Summary: every point of every cubie lies between the spheres of radii
$$
r_1 = 1 - e \sqrt{n} \\
r_2 = 1 + e \sqrt{n}
$$
From this, you can compute the volume of the inner and outer spheres (a bit of a mess, but Wikipedia will help you), and then take the difference of the two volumes and call it $U$. The total volume of your $k$ cubies will be

$k e^n$, and you know that
$k e^n \le U$, hence
$$
k \le \frac{U}{e^n}
$$

So once you did a little work looking up formulas for sphere-volumes, you'll have an answer.

Let's just do it for $\mathbb R^2$ as shown above. In this case, we have
\begin{align}
r_{1,2} = 1 \pm e \sqrt{2}
\end{align}

and the area of a disk of radius $r_1$ is
$$
A_1 = \pi (r_1)^2
$$
and similarly for $r_2$, hence the difference is
\begin{align}
U &= \pi (r_2^2 - r_1^2) \\
U &= \pi (r_1 + r_2)\cdot (r_1 - r_2) \\
U &= \pi (2)\cdot (2e\sqrt{2}) \\
U &= 4\pi e\sqrt{2} \\
\end{align}
Hence
$$
k \le \frac{4 \pi e \sqrt{2}}{e^2} = \frac{4 \pi \sqrt{2}}{e}.
$$

That actually sounds pretty reasonable: the count of cubies grows linearly in the inverse-length. If you try to work out the same formulas in 3-space, there'll be a difference-of-cubes in the numerator, which will be quadratic in $e$, and the denominator will be cubic in e, so you'll get the same general result. But there'll be extra terms, so the constant next to the $1/e$ will change with dimension in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would never have come up with the idea of bounding the number of cubies by the volume, but with Stirling's formula it turns out to be a pretty nice bound.